# Cómo crearía un campo en una tabla para que sólo se puedan insertar 2 opciones, y una de ellas salga por defecto

Tags: mysql, sql

Lo que habría que hacer sería lo siguiente:

Cliente (codcliente, nombre, direccion, email, fechaalta, telefono, ciudad, CP,
observaciones)
Articulos (codart, descripción, precio, stock)
Pedido (idpedido, codcliente, fechapedido, entregado)
Lineaspedido (idpedido, numlinea, codart, unidades)

Crear las cuatro tablas con los campos y el tipo de datos adecuado, teniendo en
cuenta que:

El campo entregado tiene dos opciones: `S` o `N`. `S` significa entregado y `N`
no entregado. `N` será la opción por defecto. **(Esta sería mi duda)**

Mi código es este:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente
( cod_cliente INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nombre CHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  direccion VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  fechaalta date() default getdate() NOT NULL,
  telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  ciudad VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  CP VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
  Observaciones VARCHAR(200) 
);
```

Pero no sé como crear el campo entregado para que tenga 2 opciones, ya que para que salga por defecto utilizaría `DEFAULT`.

Comment: ¿Y tu código? Sin código no llegamos a ninguna parte... Tiene que ser visible tu esfuerzo y el error que da tu código, este sitio fue pensado para resolver problemas en un código en específico...

Comment: Perdona, lo he editado e incluido ahora, sería la creación de ese campo llamado campo_entregado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar el tipo de dato [`ENUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html).

La definición para cumplir con tus condiciones sería la siguiente:

```
`entregado` ENUM('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N'
```

Si tu tabla ya existe, podrías agregarlo así:

```
ALTER TABLE `cliente` ADD `entregado` ENUM('S','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' AFTER `Observaciones`;
```

Si llegaras a intentar insertar un valor distinto de `S` o `N`, el error que deberías recibir (*depende de la configuración de `MySQL`*) seria:

> Data truncated for column 'entregado' at row `X`

Answer (score 0):

Seria mas practico crear un campo del tipo de dato booleano, y predeterminado `0`

Luego interpretas ese valor en tu proyecto.

```
`entregado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```